# inconsistent behavior from BigDecimal and MathContext

Tags: java, bigdecimal, mathcontext

I am Seeing some strange behavior from BigDecimal
When I do division using mathContext the output is different than when I do the division by directly providing the scale and rounding mode
Here is an example that I think should provide the same output

```
public static void main(String...args){
    MathContext mc = new MathContext(3,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal four = new BigDecimal(4);
    BigDecimal three = new BigDecimal(3);
    System.out.println(four.divide(three,3,RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    System.out.println(four.divide(three,mc));
}
```

Output:

```
1.333
1.33
```

It appears that the scale is treated differently when using MathContext. Or I dont understand when to use which.

Comment: Java's lack of named-parameters strikes hard here. The first param of  `MathContext` is significant digits, starting from the left/most. Whereas the first param of `.setScale` is digits-to-the-right-of-the-decimal-point which almost always what _I_ want when I think of "rounding."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `divide` method of `BigDecimal` lets you specify the *scale* of the result, which loosely speaking is number of decimal places.  `scale = 3` means that a number will be expressed with 3 decimal places.  A negative scale indicates the number of insignificant zeroes at the end of a whole number - so for example to round to the nearest 1000, you can specify `scale = -3`.

```
four.divide(three,3,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);  // scale = 3, so round to 3 decimal places
```

But a `MathContext` is different.  It lets you specify *precision* - that is, the number of significant digits.  This is different from *scale*.

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(3,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
four.divide(three, mc); // precision = 3, so round to 3 significant figures
```

Comment: Is there documentation somewhere for this? it wasn't in the javadocs for BigDecimal

Comment: nevermind I just looked at the documentation for mathContext and it says 'precision'